# change id of button depending on current viewed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ive a problem which is driving me crazy. im trying to explain...
i have a very long scrolling page with about 10 divs, one below the other (no space between). 
at the bottom of the viewing port is a button with an id and a position: fixed. when i scroll up or down the button is fixed while the divs move up or down.
i want to have different id's on the button depending on which div layer is in the viewing port. that means if one divlayer fills over 50% of the available space the href of the button should change...
i tried the inview.js, but the problem is, that 2 divs at the same time have the inview class...

my current code:

```
$('#div4, #div5, #div6').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
        if (visible == true) {
        $(this).addClass("inview");

        } else {

        $(this).removeClass("inview");
        }
    });





var $div4 = $('#div4');

if($div4.hasClass("inview")){
    $('#button1').attr('id', 'button2'); 
  }
```

you see, every div which is in the viewport the button gets a new id.
has anyone of you a solution?
thanks ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the `inview` class before adding it.. Something like this:

```
var $divs = $('#div4,#div5,#div6';
$divs.bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
        $divs.not(this).removeClass("inview");
        if (visible == true) {
          $(this).addClass("inview"); 
        }
     });
```

Another suggestion is to use the Waypoints plugin and fire when the div crosses the 50% mark.

The only difficult part is that depending on the direction you'll need to select the current div or the one above.

Plugin: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/nFfSn/1/

Code:

```
 $('.container div').waypoint(function (direction) {
        if (direction=='up')
            alert('hit ' + $.waypoints('above')[$.waypoints('above').length-2].id);
        else
            alert('hit ' + $(this).attr('id'));  
    }, {
        offset: $.waypoints('viewportHeight') / 2

});
```

Comment: okay this works half! it removes the inview class, but it fires directly if a few pixels of the other div are in the viewport... i only want that if the div is more than 50% in the viewing port. maybe you have another conclusion? thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer to an alternate solution using jquery waypoints.

Comment: Glad it helps.  If it answers your question please click the green checkmark next to the answer!

Comment: wait one thing... how can i start an event when, for example, div id="fourth" is in view... 

http://jsfiddle.net/HMWT6/
thats how i thought, but it still fires on every div!

Comment: It depends if you want a specific div by ID or a specific index.  Here is an example of both to give you an idea of how it could be done. http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/F3m9a/2/

Comment: i need it for id, and im almost getting it! but why it does alert the 4th div twice? im scrolling down and first "3 by id" then "4 by id"... everythings okay. but on scrolling up it shows "4 by id" again when 50% of the 3rd is in the viewport! wheres the mistake!

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F3m9a/5/
hope its okay asking you again and again :D

Comment: Just a typo on the variable name (I changed it but forgot in one place).  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/F3m9a/6/